# What test equipment can simulate the inductive load of a DC motor?

Tags: power, motor, dc-motor, test-equipment, electronic-load

I am working on a power supply circuit designed to drive DC motor. Currently, I am testing using the actual DC motor, but I would like to start using test equipment instead. There are several options on the market for electronic DC loads (BK Precision and Keysight), but none of these seem to be able to simulate the inductive properties of the motor such as inrush current and the inductive voltage spike when the power relay opens. Are there any sorts of test equipment that can better simulate this?

Examples of programable DC loads:

[BK Precision 8600 Series](https://www.bkprecision.com/products/dc-electronic-loads/8614-1500-w-programmable-dc-electronic-load.html)

[Keysight EL30000 Series](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/products/dc-electronic-loads/el30000-series-bench-electronic-loads.html)

Comment: What is wrong with using the actual DC motor, or two coupled together to simulate a mechanical load?

Comment: Motor start current is not an inductive property but related to inertia and mechanical load. I've never heard of any attempt to emulate this other than by using ... a motor, on a mechanical test rig.

Comment: Define start and run current and voltage then an active inductor load can be designed cheaply with an L/DCR ratio spec if you have one. Load may change up to 100:1 for no mechanical load. Or 100:10 for full mechanical load with same L

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, can you point me to some reading on active inductor loads? Also, I'm not sure what the L/DCR ratio spec is...

Comment: I don’t know of any. But you can measure DCR and state the other specs

Comment: As well as inductance, to properly emulate a DC motor you need a voltage which is proportional to rpm and absorbs as well as produces current. You also need a way to emulate the inertia of the armature and load, current ripple, and brush/commutator noise - all of which may have a marked effect on power supply performance.

Answer (score 3):

erlectrically a motor looks something like this.

R1 is mechanical losses like friction and the mechanical load
R2 is magnetic losses like eddy currents
R3 is the resistance of the motor
C1 is the innertia of the motor and whatever it's attached to, C1 causes the inrush current

L1 is the motors leakage inductance it causes the turn-off fireworks.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkGw4C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You reference C2 in your description but it appears to be omitted in the schematic.

Comment: Actually I meant C1