# DC motor emulation

Tags: pwm, dc-motor

We need to interface with third-party system which only has 24V 3A 30kHz PWM motor outputs. Furthermore, their software stops working if it detects problems with motors. So, I am looking for a solution that will emulate the presence of the motor and measure the duty cycle and direction at the same time.

Just to begin with something, I've tried 2k resistor and got "actuator disconnected" error. With 500 Ohm resistor there was no startup error, but when power was applied the "check wiring" error popped up. I think if I reduce resistor even more it will eventually start working, but the heat dissipation will be unacceptable. The DC resistance of the real actuators is 21.5 Ohm.

Now I am thinking that resistor and inductor combination (or even something like [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/572925/187920)) will be better. But I have no idea how to calculate correct inductance.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why emulate? Why not use the motor?

Comment: @Andyaka Because the mentioned third-party system does not operate the way we need it to. Unfortunately we _must_ use it as input device. The only way we could think of is to capture its PWM outputs, process them on our MCU and then drive actuators ourselves. The manufacturer of that system flat out refused to give us any other output format (we asked for simple serial)

Comment: @Andyaka despite of how ridiculous it sounds, this is the same way the product of the _parent company_ of this manufacturer connects to these devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most motor driver circuits contain a H-bridge with current sense shunt resistor in the low side path of the MOSFETs. If you provide a small auxiliary voltage and feed this into the motor terminals, the shunt will receive a fake motor current signal.

This solution will dissipate 2-4 W, I estimate, while simulating 50 W motor power. With luck, 1 V will be sufficient and you can trim R2 down.

However, your next error message may be "motor stall"..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fumEIP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is unexpected approach, exactly of a kind I was asking for. Let me ponder it a bit. Not sure yet if it is compatible with PWM capturing circuit I have in mind. Actually... it makes me eager to open up their modules and see what kind of driver chip or sensing circuit they are using.

Comment: OK, let's see if I got this right. 1) this circuit does not generate voltage on Rsense when bridge if open, which is great. I missed this detail on first look over. 2) when any of the low side FETs is closed the circuit generates constant feedback voltage independent of duty cycle. This voltage can be higher than expected, especially at short duty pulses (motor inductance supposed to keep current low), resulting in false short circuit detection. 3) this circuit will not work with devices using different sensing, like high-side current mirrors in many new TI drivers. ...

Comment: ... 4) in some PWM modes (like low-side recirculation phase) this may also trigger an error if controller detects current when it does not expect any. 5) since external voltage is applied to both H-bridge outputs it does not affect whatever PWM sensing circuit I can come up with.

Comment: @Maple Many motor drivers use low side PWM only, so at least the average voltage across R1 would depend on the PWM duty cycle. Give it a run, you may have luck. If there is high side current sensing, you can mirror the circuit with V2 at the +24 side. Have a look with a scope to see how it is implemented.

Comment: You are right, I need to scope that thing. Or better yet, open it up and see what they have on output stage. I'll do that and update the question when I know more.

Comment: I've opened up the driver module. Each channel has 4 FETs that could be [PSMN8R3_40YS](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/916/PSMN8R3_40YS-2938856.pdf) , a pair of TSSOP-8 chips that could be gate drivers and QFN-10 chip that could be hall current sensor, at least it sits in the break of power trace to connector. I was unable to identify the chips from the markings. Does not look promising, but I guess it should not damage anything to try your idea.

Comment: Well, if this doesn't work, you can still connect the motor terminals to a rectifier, a big cap and a boost converter to send the power back to the 24 V bus :)

Comment: Oh, cool! Then I wouldn't need a battery at all! :)