# Capture PWM duty and polarity

Tags: pwm

This question is a spin-off from [earlier post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/642902/187920) about DC motor emulation. I've decided to split the questions to keep them more on point. Assuming I can successfully trick the driver into thinking the real motor is attached, the next step would be to capture PWM duty and polarity. The driver output is rated for 12-24V, 3-15A actuators with 30kHz PWM frequency.

I am planning to use input capture feature of STM32L4 timers to measure the duty cycle. But I am running out of timer channels, so the ideal solution would be to use one channel per motor driver.

At present, the idea is to have two optical isolators in parallel, one bi-directional (AC input), another is not (DC input). The former feeds into input capture pin of the MCU, the latter is connected to plain GPIO.

**Question:** Does this look like workable solution or is there something simpler?

UPDATE:

The first attempt failed miserably. I bought cheap optoisolators without looking at their switching characteristics and they were too slow to capture 30kHz PWM. I need at least 100 (ideally 1000) steps resolution. So I started looking at faster options and ended up with 3 choices:

1. Digital isolators with passive input (e.g. [IL600A](https://www.nve.com/Downloads/il600a.pdf)). These seem to be perfect, as there is no input voltage limitation. They also have excellent 5ns max PWM distortion. But to capture duty in both directions I'd need rectifier bridge on the input.
2. Optoisolators with logic output (e.g. [TLP2367](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/TLP2367_datasheet_en_20171025.pdf?did=36692&prodName=TLP2367)). Also no voltage limitation, slightly worse propagation delay. Could not find suitable AC input chips, so will need a bridge as well. As a side note, it is really strange that these chips are on average 10 times faster than photovoltaic isolators working on the same principle.
3. Digital isolators (e.g. [ISO7710](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso7710.pdf)). These have the best switching characteristics and are readily available in 4-8 channel packages. But they require signal conditioning to logic levels and power supply on the input side. Way too cumbersome.

Are there better options to interface MCU with DC motor driver output?

UPDATE 2:

OK, since I did not get any suggestions, here is how I am going to proceed. The PWM pulses from two isolators connected in opposite directions will be OR'ed to be captured by single MCU pin. The rising edge will start DMA transfer of both period and duty counters, eliminating the need in IRQ processing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frIlIZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That leaves me with a question how to capture direction at the same time. Ideally it would be to inject GPIO port state into the same DMA stream with timers, but I don't think it is possible. I am thinking a D trigger clocked by rising edge of the PWM pulses can hold the direction state for later retrieval.

Comment: You could emulate a motor with a very complex load, but how do you plan on doing this? you would have to have a micro with the motor dynamics and the ability to emulate an inductive load. That would be a lot of math and testing to get it to work properly.

Comment: Also, how is this different from the previous question

Comment: @VoltageSpike your comment is related to motor emulation. Would you mind posting it to the linked question? Jens provided very clever suggestion on how to do it. I am planning on testing that soon. This question is about reading the motor command.